# Figma flatten doesn't show my vector shape

Tags: vector, figma, flatten

So I tried to combine several vectors of an illustration component and when I flatten them, it doesn't really work. I tried to union them first and then flatten and still doesn't work.
Is there maybe something wrong with the way that illustration is created?

Many thanks!

[image: combined vector shape not showing]
[image: vector layers]

Comment: Did you try union with all selected at the same time? Have you tried Flatten without union? Before or after you turn everything into a component? I can't reproduce the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because you are trying to flatten/boolean two pieces of an object that are inside instances. Instances are indicated by the diamond icon in the layers panel. Components have a four diamond shaped icon.

You can't do that in Figma. The flatten and union boolean operations will be grayed-out and unavailable for objects inside instances.

[image]

I don't know why you have instances of components inside other components. The construction is a bit over complicated TBH. Not sure if you did this or are trying to fix something someone else did, but in general, I would try to avoid complex nesting of instances and components like that, if you possibly can. It just makes it harder to work out how something is constructed.

Anyway, one method to fix it might be to select individual pieces inside the instances, and copy them, and get them out of those instances by pasting somewhere else on the artboard outside of the instances.

Another method you could try is to right click the instances and break the link to the component by selecting "Detach Instance".

Once you just have vectors, select them and you should be able to boolean/flatten them.